# How to use insert into function with subquery?

Tags: sqlplus, insert-into

I can run the query below by itself to look for the employee_id for the new teacher, Harvey, and add the value into the insert into function, but I'm getting an error saying it's not properly ended. The other two fields are hard-coded instead.

```
INSERT INTO expertise(employee_id, course_code, expertise_level)
VALUES (employee_id, CMPP201, 1)
SELECT employee_id
FROM faculty
WHERE employee_id = (SELECT employee_id
                     FROM faculty
                     WHERE firstname = 'Harvey');
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: And you don't need the subquery. Just use the WHERE clause from the subquery.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I've got it. Thanks to everyone who has replied to this thread.